# What term predated "even" when referring to numbers?

Tags: etymology, numbers, mathematical-language

In doing some poking around in etymologies, I noticed that while "odd" in the sense of "odd number" is attested as early as c.1300 (and is in fact the original sense of the term), "even" in the sense of "even number" isn't attested until the mid-16th century. Do we have any examples of what terms were used to describe even numbers during that gap?

Comment: This looks like an interesting question for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that stackexchange. I'll post it over there instead; thanks!